# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute face

Tags: python, anaconda, face-recognition

OpenCV is not working for face recognizer.

I am using Python@3.6.3 with a compatible OpenCV version (*supported for Python@3.6.x in Anaconda*).

[image]

Comment: I would suggest copying the code from the screenshot and putting it within your question as a codeblock.

Comment: @Giri kolka I am facing same issue, pls post your answer here if this problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing  [`opencv-contrib`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) and it should work.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```